# saving a file from eclipse to submit for school-java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to send my teacher my eclipse java files. every time i get them out of eclipse they turn into an compiled file and then when they go back into eclipse they look absolutely crazy. I'm sure their is an easy answer to why this is happening, but i can't figure it out for the life of me.

anyone experienced in eclipse that can help me out?

Thank you

Comment: You're probably copying the .class (compiled classes) instead of .java (source code) files.

Comment: I have done both to make sure I wasn't doing it wrong. When i copy the .java out and click on it it automatically opens in Sublime text editor and it looks perfect, but if it try to reopen it in eclipse it looks like crazy hieroglyphics

Comment: nvm thank you, that helped me figure it out. your were mostly right. i was just copying it wrong. thank you so much!